# Can't find Makefile of editorconfig-core-c

Tags: linux, makefile, editorconfig

I am trying to install **editorconfig-core-c**. So I followed the following tutorial:

[Tutorial of editorconfig-core-c](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-core-c/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

So I needed to do:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libpcre3-dev
```

and

```
make install
```

But in which folder is the **Makefile**? I didn't found anything in ~/

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?

Comment: Did you run cmake? It should generate a makefile.

Comment: I can't even find the right folder.

Comment: You need to run `cmake dir` where `dir` is the directory containing `CMakeLists.txt` (the root top-level directory of editorconfig-core-c in this case), this will output a Makefile in your current directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the below commands to make, install it and then remove the downloaded files. The key steps you need are

- Install any prerequisites
- Download the source
- Run `cmake .` in the downloaded directory to create the `makefile`
- Install with `sudo make install`

A complete set of the commands needed is provided below.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libpcre3-dev git
cd
git clone https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-core-c.git
cd editorconfig-core-c/
cmake .
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -rf editorconfig-core-c/
```